# Using Google Contacts Api in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-api

currently I've implemented Google Contacts API to my Vue Web Page:

```
gapi.auth.authorize(this.configGoogle, () => {
   this.fetchContacts(gapi.auth.getToken());
});
```

Now in my React Native App, I cant find a way to implement this, do I need a plugin to sign in into Google Account? and then use Google Contact API JS to fetch contacts? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use this https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-google-signin

Use the plugin above, it will pop up for google sign in. After you get the ACCESS_TOKEN, you can use it to call the google api to get the contacts.

Here is a article to tell you what to do: https://medium.com/@aleenavadayil1995/google-contacts-api-in-react-native-53107115056c

Just a bit of heads up about react-native-google-signin, for the Android version, please be mindful that to generate the SHA1 from ~/.android/debug.keystore, which has taken me a long time to figure out.